# Better spacing in section title

Tags: spacing, header-footer, hyphenation

Consider the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section title with a long final woorddddddd}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following result

[image]

As you can see, the final word gets hyphenated leaving only two letters on the first line. A preferable solution to me is to stretch the initial part of the title so that it fills the first line and the final word is moved entirely to the second line.

At the same time, I still like the look of the page header, and any fix should be local to the section title. For example, changing the `\section` call to

`\section{This is a section title with a long final\\ woorddddddd}`

produces the following output

[image]

As a workaround, I thought I could call `\markright` before and after the call to `\section` (basically I can manually fix any ugly-looking space in the header). Is there a better/cleaner solution?

Comment: `\section[This is a section title with a long final woorddddddd]{This is a section title with a long final\\ woorddddddd}`

Comment: Yeah that works neatly! Please post it as answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in the command below:

```
\section[This is a section title with a long final woorddddddd]
  {This is a section title with a long final\\ woorddddddd}
```

is only acceptable for rare or unique cases. A more general solution could be this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \pretocmd{\section}{\raggedright}{}{}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
  \pretocmd{\section}{\raggedright}{}{}

\begin{document}

 \section{This is a section title with a long final woorddddddd}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that the first solution only works in rare cases? sorry if it's trivial

Comment: What I meant is that the first solution is fine if there are few cases, on which to intervene manually. The second one works fine even if you will change the layout or the font features since it automatically composes text with left alignment in all cases